# simple grails GSON plugin usage

Tags: grails, gson

I am trying to use this super good plugin:
https://github.com/robfletcher/grails-gson/blob/master/test/apps/gson-test/grails-app/controllers/grails/plugin/gson/test/AlbumController.groovy

because the default GRAILS JSON does not expand the related items.

However when I try it, it fails.

Now, when i do this, it works:

```
def levelJson() {

    render ToolType.list(params) as JSON
}
```

This fails:

```
def levelJson() {

    render ToolType.list(params) as GSON
}
```

Error:

```
ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - UnsupportedOperationException occurred when processing request: [GET] /authtools/toolType/levelJson
Attempted to serialize java.lang.Class: org.hibernate.proxy.HibernateProxy. Forgot to register a type adapter?. Stacktrace follows:
Message: Attempted to serialize java.lang.Class: org.hibernate.proxy.HibernateProxy. Forgot to register a type adapter?
```

Classes:

```
class Artist {
    String name
    static hasMany = [albums: Album]
}

class Album {
    String title
    static belongsTo = Artist
}
```

Comment: How does `ToolType` look like? Have a look at [Serialization](https://github.com/robfletcher/grails-gson#serialization) as a pre-requisite.

Comment: OK - that was the solution..  I did not realize that static belongsTo = [tolltype: ToolType]; was not the same as static belongsTo = ToolType;

Comment: @dmahapatro do you want to answer?  You were right.

Comment: I am good as long as it is helpful. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution as dmahapatro pointed out was to modify the data class belongsTo

Before (not working):

```
class Album {
    String title
    static belongsTo = Artist
}
```

After (working):

```
class Album {
    String title
    static belongsTo = [artist: Artist]
}
```